# How do I save everything after / into a variable using PHP?

Tags: php, variables, url, proxy

Currently I have a proxy made in PHP that works the following: `https://proxyurl/url=` but I want to get rid of the `url=` and just put the url after the slash. Then I want to save everything that is entered after the slash into a `$url` variable inside of PHP. How would I go about doing this?

My current code:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $url = $_GET['url'];

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the URL that you want to GET by using the CURLOPT_URL option.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    //Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER so that the content is returned as a variable.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Execute the request.
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //Close the cURL handle.
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;

?>
```

For example: `https://proxyurl/https://google.com` - where `https://google.com` is the `$url`

or `https://proxyurl/google.com` where `google.com` is the `$url`

Comment: You can do this using .htaccess mod_rewrite where you can define that proxyurl.com/www.google.com equals proxyurl.com/?url=www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using something more like this : `https://proxyurl/?url=google.com`. You don't have to change anything to your php code.

As elMeroMero said you need to use [mode_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in any Apache configuration file. You can use it with a .htaccess file in your root directory. You would have to had something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) ?url=$1 [L]
```

I am not a mode_rewrite specialist, maybe someone else will revise my suggestion.